# Why is backward elimination justified when doing multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, bootstrap, reliability, overfitting, jackknife

Does it not result in over-fitting? Would my results be more reliable if I added a jack-knife or bootstrap procedure as a part of the analysis?

Comment: Who says it's justified? Of course it should lead to overfitting.

Comment: It is actually suggested in many books (still?), e.g. http://www.amazon.com/Statistics-Explained-Introductory-Guide-Scientists/dp/0521183286/r. I have been thinking the same issue myself. I think I have at least 3-4 statistics books that do not discuss the overfitting issue at all, when introducing multiple regression.

Comment: Honestly, if an introductory statistic book does not discuss overfitting and over testing, I would read a different book.

Comment: Backward elimination (and forward selection) still tends to over-fit if leave-one-out cross-validation (e.g. PRESS) is used as the feature selection criterion.

Comment: I would welcome book suggestions. (Though this is getting a bit off-topic.)

Comment: @mmh not quite introductory, but I highly recommend reading chapter 4 of Frank Harrell's *Regression Modelling Strategies* (well, it's not just chapter 4 that's worth reading, but that part's especially relevant to this discussion).

Answer (score 2):

I think building a model and testing it are different things. The backward elimination is part of model building. Jack knife and bootstrap are more used to test it.

You can certainly have more reliable estimates with bootstrap and jack knife than the simple backward eleimination. But if you really want to test overfitting, the ultimate test is a split-sample, train on some, test on others. Leave-one-out is too unstable/unreliable for this purpose:
http://www.russpoldrack.org/2012/12/the-perils-of-leave-one-out.html

I think at least 10% of subjects need to be out to get more stable estimates of robustness of the model. And if you have 20 subjects, 2 subjects are still very few. But then the question becomes whether you have a large enough sample to build a model that can be applied to the rest of the population.

Hope it answered your question at least in part.

Comment: So one could just use cross-validation with $k < n$ (or $k << n$)?

Comment: [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf) discusses different approaches to resampling (validation sets, cross-validation with different numbers of groups, bootstrapping) in Chapter 5, and model selection in Chapter 6.